# Linux env variable with newlines + sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, echo

I've got a command that I run that outputs to stdio that I need to redirect to an existing file, replacing the word `replaceme` with the two lines output by my command.

The command `mycommand` outputs like this:
somedata=this
somedata=that

I'm able to get the output into an environment variable:

```
export TWOLINES=$(mycommand)
```

When I echo it back out it comes out as a single line

```
echo $TWOLINES
```

Returns:
somedata1=this somedata2=that

I need to get this content into my `file` as two lines

Attempting to do:

```
sed -e "s,replaceme,${TWOLINES}," -i file
```

Returns: unterminated 's' command

Thoughts or other tools besides sed that could assist?

Comment: Use quotes: `echo "$TWOLINES"`.

Comment: [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021) provides tools that -- unlike `sed` -- work with completely arbitrary source and replacement strings; no problem with newlines, no need for a sigil variable (`,` in your example) that can't be present in the contents. See the `gsub_literal` function for which source is provided in said FAQ for one such example.

Comment: BTW, in general, you shouldn't use an environment variable unless you know why you need one (instead of using a regular shell variable). The more environment variables you have defined, and the longer their contents, the shorter maximum command line length you can use when starting other commands.